# Screen becomes blank for long time while loading SherlockFragmentActivity with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

I am implementing jeremyfeinstein sliding menu library. for this I have an activity which extends SherlockFragmentActivity. for this activity I have two fragments one is for left menu and another is for Main screen. Everything is working fine and smooth but still I have a problem that is when my Sliding menu activity starts, it becomes blank for 8-10 seconds. after 8-10 seconds my main screen fragment becomes visible.
**this is my base class:**

```
  public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {

    private SlidingActivityHelper mHelper;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHelper = new SlidingActivityHelper(this);
        mHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHelper.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#findViewById(int)
     */
    @Override
    public View findViewById(int id) {
        View v = super.findViewById(id);
        if (v != null)
            return v;
        return mHelper.findViewById(id);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#setContentView(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int id) {
        setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, null));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#setContentView(android.view.View)
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View v) {
        setContentView(v, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#setContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View v, LayoutParams params) {
        super.setContentView(v, params);
        mHelper.registerAboveContentView(v, params);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setBehindContentView(int)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(int id) {
        setBehindContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, null));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setBehindContentView(android.view.View)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(View v) {
        setBehindContentView(v, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setBehindContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(View v, LayoutParams params) {
        mHelper.setBehindContentView(v, params);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#getSlidingMenu()
     */
    public SlidingMenu getSlidingMenu() {
        return mHelper.getSlidingMenu();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        mHelper.toggle();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#showAbove()
     */
    public void showContent() {
        mHelper.showContent();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#showBehind()
     */
    public void showMenu() {
        mHelper.showMenu();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#showSecondaryMenu()
     */
    public void showSecondaryMenu() {
        mHelper.showSecondaryMenu();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setSlidingActionBarEnabled(boolean)
     */
    public void setSlidingActionBarEnabled(boolean b) {
        mHelper.setSlidingActionBarEnabled(b);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onKeyUp(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean b = mHelper.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        if (b) return b;
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Here is my Main activity which loads fragments

```
public class SliderMenuMainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity
{
private Fragment mContent;
    ImageButton btnToggle,refresh;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    public static int msg_count = 0;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(obj==null)
            obj=new Progress_Dialog(this);
        obj.setCancelable(false);
        obj.onPreExecute("MAIN Screen");
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        prepareScreen();
    }
private void prepareScreen()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider_menu_main);
        
        ActionBar ab = getSherlock().getActionBar();
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_titlebar, null);
        customView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ab.setCustomView(customView);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) 
        {
            setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
            getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(true);
            getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
            // show home as up so we can toggle
            //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // add a dummy view
            View v = new View(this);
            setBehindContentView(v);
            getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);
            getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
        }

        
        if (mContent == null)
            mContent = new MainScreenFragment();    
        
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent).commit();

        // set the Behind View Fragment
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuFragment()).commit();

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.25f);
        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
        
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    }
    public void switchContent(final Fragment fragment) {
        mContent = fragment;
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        .commit();
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getSlidingMenu().showContent();
            }
        }, 50);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(obj!=null)
            obj.onPostExecute();
    }
}
```

So please help me with this and show me a way to overcome this problem. thanks in advance.

### EDIT 1

I have placed all the code to the onResume() but it still have same problem. now it is taking about 2 to 3 second to become activity visible.why it is taking this amount of time when I don't have any code into onCreate(). I have removed all the libraries and now I am using only support library(4 and 7) with navigation drawer with same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

blank screen displayed because your content view is not set up until `prepareScreen` executes.

**Solution:**

you need to put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider_menu_main);` directly after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` inside `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanx for quick reply. let me check it.

Comment: still same problem... :(

Comment: what is `obj` ? if you are trying to show progress dialog while just loading your views,then it is not necessary at all to do that.you can remove it without any fear.

Comment: Yes I have removed that but it does not change the result.

Comment: I have removed everything from onCreate() and added code to onResume() but it still takes about 1 seconds time to become visible

Answer (score 0):

You are doing lot of operations in onCreate(). You need to just set the primary layout and stuff like that. all the operations can be called in onResume().

Comment: Yes you are right. I am doing lot of operations in onCreate() but these are the requirement of my project. if I do these operations in onResume() then they will be called every time instead on single time like onCreate().

Comment: So what you can do it put all these operations inside AsyncTask and call it in onCreate(). The operations executing in the main thread is the problem

Comment: Yes I have tried by removing all the operations from onCreate() but again takes same time. you can also check it by running above piece of code.