# how to reduce activity launch time

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using Navigation drawer in my application. for this I have support libraries included in my project(support library 7 and 4). everything is fine and working well but I have a problem that is when my main activity launches then it becomes blank for 2 to 3 seconds. my main activity contains code for the navigation drawer. I have placed all the code to onResume(). I have tried different ways to overcome this problem but every time I face same problem. is this the standard time which an activity takes to become visible or it is something unexpected behavior of my app. earlier I tried with actionbarsherlock but Now I removed it. so please suggest me a possible solution to this problem.

I have more description to this problem here[Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041137/screen-becomes-blank-for-long-time-while-loading-sherlockfragmentactivity-with-f/20046470?noredirect=1#comment30023241_20046470)

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons behind slow loading of activity
Probably you are using a complex layout file which takes time to render. You could use [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) and inflate your layouts only when required

if you are loading some data you could use an asynctask to load the data in background and populate views when data is loaded.

Check if you are loading large images in oncreate or onresume.

also some more reference from [Android Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html)